# IOS PHP communication

Tags: php, ios, server, transfer

I need to send data from my phone to my server. I don't need to encrypt them.I just need to be sure that the data comes from my app and not from someone refreshing the browser. How can I do this. Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want authentication, the best way would be to sign the data with a **private key** on your app and **verify** the signature with the **public key** on the server.

Comment: I thought of this.But what stops the hacker to catch the url and refresh the browser.

Comment: @user663942 I don't understand you, if your **private key is safe**, no one should be able to sign the data as you, on the other hand to refresh the browser you need to have done the request first in order to _refresh_ it, so as I understand the browser shouldn't have the request of your app unless your app is running on the browser... and then... the data is actually coming from your app.

Comment: Yes you are right.SO to be clear. I am sending encrypted data to my php server and getting the data with $_POST.There i will decrypt it and verify the signing.No?

Comment: @user663942: I was saying you can send **signed data** so you will be sure of the origin (**authentication**. If you **encrypt** it, no one without the key should be able to **understand** what you have sent. It's not the same, and you can do both if what you want is to be sure of the **origin and integrity** (_signed data_) and also have **secret comunication** (_encrypted data_). You can check those links: [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure), [Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) and [Digital Signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand fully your question but recommend you take a look at ASIHTTPRequest

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Or the standard NSURLConnection

Comment: The problem with ASIHTTPRequest is that it conflicts with my sharekit library.

Comment: You will find that they both just duplicate Reachability, just delete the files from one :)

PS - Read the debug output when the error occurs! :-)

Comment: Did you remove it from ShareKit though?

[link](http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest/browse_thread/thread/331ddffff6c9d9fc)

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would be adding custom http header and validate the same in the server side script. 
This will at least reduce no. of ppl who don't have right tools for the job.